# TYPO3 multilingual website content localization

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

I am creating my first website in TYPO3 with TemplaVoila. 
I followed the tutorial: http://www.training-typo3.com/2008/12/15/typo3-multi-language/ to make my site multilingual. Everything works fine except when I choose a language other than default language in the frontend, page shows content in every language.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it. Added following line to main ts template.

```
    config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a typoscript setting, can you put the the URL and your main typoscript setup here?